# Can I read the synced iBooks books from iTunes as well?

Tags: itunes, books

I've noticed there is a new category in my iTunes (Books), with all the boocks I synced from the iPad.

Can I read books in iTunes on my computer as well ?

If not, there is some other way to read them, since they are stored on my mac ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The books and PDFs are stored, as all other media files (if media organization is turned on), in your iTunes Media Folder (Music/iTunes/iTunes Media). You can use [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/) or any other [ePub reader for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/170612/epub-reader-for-mac-os-x) to read them.